# Two Columns layout in CSS - text and image changing order in each row

Tags: html, css

Can you help me and tell me what's wrong in my CSS Code?
It looks like this:

```
body
        {
            font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
            padding: 5rem 1.25rem; /* 80 20 */
        }

        .container
        {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 60rem; /* 960 */
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
            .item
            {
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-bottom: 5rem; /* 80 */
            }
            }
            .item
            {
                color: #666;
            }
                .item__info,
                .item__img
                {
                    width: 50%;
                    float: left;
                }
                .item:nth-child( even ) .item__info
                {
                    float: right;
                    padding-left: 1.25rem; /* 20 */
                }
                .item:nth-child( even ) .item__img
                {
                    padding-right: 1.25rem; /* 20 */
                }
                .item:nth-child( odd ) .item__info
                {
                    padding-right: 1.25rem; /* 20 */
                }
                .item:nth-child( odd ) .item__img
                {
                    padding-left: 1.25rem; /* 20 */
                }
                .item__img
                {
                }
                    .item__img
                    {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 18.750rem; /* 300 */
                    }

                .item h2
                {
                    font-weight: 700;
                    font-size: 1.875rem; /* 30 */
                    margin-bottom: 0.625rem; /* 10 */
                }
                .item p
                {
                    line-height: 1.625rem; /* 26 */
                }
```

and the html for that is simple:

```
    <div class="container" role="main">

    <article class="item">
        <div class="item__info">
            <h2>Header1</h2>
            <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item__img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450"/></div>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
        <div class="item__info">
            <h2>Header2</h2>
            <p>Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item__img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450"/></div>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
        <div class="item__info">
            <h2>Header3</h2>
            <p>Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item__img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450"/></div>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
        <div class="item__info">
            <h2>Header4</h2>
            <p>Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item__img"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450"/></div>
    </article>



</div>
```

I created the jsfiddle for that, it's [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhtv31qj/). The effect that I wanted to achieve looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiOEw.png). What did go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following. let me know if the issue is still there. :)

```css
body {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  padding: 5rem 1.25rem;
  /* 80 20 */
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  /* 960 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  /* 80 */
}
.item {
  color: #666;
}
.item__info,
.item__img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.item:nth-child(even) .item__info {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  /* 20 */
}
.item:nth-child(even) .item__img {
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
  /* 20 */
}
.item:nth-child(odd) .item__info {
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
  /* 20 */
}
.item:nth-child(odd) .item__img {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  /* 20 */
}
.item h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  /* 30 */
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  /* 10 */
}
.item p {
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  /* 26 */
}
.item__img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18.750rem;
  /* 300 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container" role="main">
  <article class="item">
    <div class="item__info">
      <h2>Header1</h2>

      <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__img">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="item__info">
      <h2>Header2</h2>

      <p>Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2 Text2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__img">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="item__info">
      <h2>Header3</h2>

      <p>Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3 Text3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__img">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
    <div class="item__info">
      <h2>Header4</h2>

      <p>Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4 Text4.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__img">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: `1. Click to answer box, 2. Then press CTRL + M` or find markup icon in toolbar :)

Comment: One more thing - currently it's visible in two columns as text/picture picture/text text/picture, etc. If I want to change it in the future to the standard text/picture text/picture text/picture etc. - is there only one small change in the CSS required? or does it require me to rewrite most of the css code?

Comment: Just remove/comment this class if you want them standardize  `.item:nth-child(even) .item__info`

Comment: Hey, one more thing to that topic - I tried both layouts and now I would also like to see it as picture/text, picture/text, picture/text etc. Could you give me a hint if there's a quick fix in the current css code?

Comment: just remove `.item:nth-child(even) .item__info` this

Answer (score 1):

There are really much, much simpler ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.  This is not responsive, but, should help you get going in the right direction.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="twoColumns">
    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
</div>

<div id="twoColumns">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />

    <h2>Text</h2>
    <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#twoColumns {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        /* column counts can be changed for num. of columns */
        column-count: 2;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="twoColumns">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>
        
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="twoColumns">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YV59Utw.jpg" height="275" width="450" />
        
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1 Text1</p>
    </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeQ/mtn2obmj/

Also, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) link on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to learn about the CSS Columns property.

Answer (score 0):

Your `item__img` is overwritten by this code:

```
 .item__img   {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18.750rem; /* 300 */
 }
```

It is 100% width insted of the 50% intended.

You should also lower the width to account for the padding and margin if you want it to line up properly it should look like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVNJq) (note the `width: 47%`)